# Extend Excel Formula Without Overwriting Background Color

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, formatting

In Excel 2010, how can I extend a formula down (updating cell references) and avoid overwriting the background and fonts of the cells below it?

For example, if I have the following Excel spreadsheet

[image: Example Spreadsheet]

How could I extend the formula in `$B$1` down through rows 2, 3, and 4 without changing their background color to light blue, and making sure that the reference to `A1` in the formula gets updated to `A2`, `A3` and so on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there is indeed another option:

[image]

And when you pick 'Fill without Formatting', your formulas will be copied without the background being copied over.

[Note for formulas, you won't get "Fill Series", I just got the picture from google =P]

I still prefer using the paste formulas only, since I can easily put it in the quick access toolbar and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + [Some number] as shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

- Right click on the cell containing the formula (in this case, `B1`) and select **Copy**
- Select the range you want to extend the formula to (in this case, `$B$2:$B$4`)
- Right click on the selected range, and click on **Formula** option under **Paste Options**

  [image: Paste Options]

*Note: this is just the way I found to do it. If anyone knows a better/easier way, please feel free to post it as an answer, and I will accept your answer.*